# How to add a tags to autocomplete - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an autocomplete drop down and i am trying to add a tags to the list. When i populate the availableTags array and run the project, it works fine as below

**File.JS**

```
var availableTags = [];
$(document).ready(function(){
$(function() {
    $( "#search-product" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags     
    }
    });
  });  
});


function getItems(token,id)
{  
     $.ajax({
        url: "/get/product/items",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            _token: token,
            id:id,
        },
        success: (dataResult) => {
            availableTags.length = 0
            $.each(dataResult, function(index,products) {
              
               availableTags.push(products.name,products.price);

              }); 
        },
    });
}
```

Is there a way i can populate the the ul list with my a tags as below. This is what i have tried and when i run the project, it returns empty list.

Is there something i am doing wrong ?

**JS**

```
 function getItems(token,id)
    {  
         $.ajax({
            url: "/get/product/items",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                _token: token,
                id:id,
            },
            success: (dataResult) => {
                availableTags.length = 0
                $.each(dataResult, function(index,products) {
                  
           availableTags.push( $(".ui-autocomplete").append('<li class="ui-menu-item" role="presentation"><a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">Apple & Samsung</a></li>'));
    
                  }); 
            },
        });
    }
```

Comment: Why adding html in availableTags after api call?

Comment: Shouldn't be just adding items

Comment: @NavnathJadhav Yes, but i need a way to add insert html tags into the ul

Comment: Upon api call completed? right?

Comment: Yes exactly @NavnathJadhav. Any idea how i can get this done ?

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 0):

You have missing some syntax here:

```
var availableTags = [];
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( function() {
        $( "#search-product" ).autocomplete({
          source: availableTags
        });
    } );
});
```

In Success call back:

```
success: (dataResult) => {
    availableTags.length = 0;
    $.each(dataResult, function(index,products) {
       availableTags.push(products.name,products.price);
    });
    $("#search-product").autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
   });
}
```

Comment: It is not about just adding the items. As stated in the question above, when i add items, it works fine. But i want to insert HTML. That is what i am looking at doing

Comment: I am not seeing any HTML insertion in your answer

Comment: Are you looking to modify the html of those dropdown options?

Comment: You does not need to modify JqueryUI autocomplete options in DOM directly. Just do `$("#search-product").autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
   });` It will add new tags.

Comment: Thank you but that is not what i am searching for. I know when you add values to the availableTags array, it creates new tags. But what i am searching for is to add my own custom tags